# Translucent status bar with imageview in collapsible toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to set image to collapsible toolbar which is shown behind the translucent status bar for >23api. But even after setting the statusbar to be transparent in styles.xml and applying the theme from manifest for the activity and setting fitSystemWindows in layout for the imageview and collapsingToolbar, the image isnt applies to status bar. The xml and the screenshot on how it looks:

Layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:id="@+id/movie_banner"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/movies_details_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        style="@style/FabStyle"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

This is how it looks on my phone.

[image: Image not setting on transparent statusbar]

--------------------Update--------------------
Jakson's answer solved it partially. Now, the image is set to status bar while the toolbar is scrolling up but, once it's fully up, I see like the image below. Note that the actionbar has also moved a bit up.
I need to achieve something like this: [image set over statusbar](http://antonioleiva.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/collapsing-toolbar-layout.png)
[image]

Comment: show your latest xml

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now. Apparently missed fitSystemWindows in appbarlayout. Works good now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create a values-v21 folder in res folder

and apply this theme to your current activity

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

in your styles.xml

```
    <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
```

also set fitsystemwindows to CoordinatorLayout,AppBarLayout,CollapsingToolbarLayout and Imageview

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solved my problem partially. can you check my updated question?

Comment: Thanks saved my day

Comment: Hi mate. Please, could you explain more about the folder "values-v21"? I created the directory and then I created a file callled "styles.xml" and put the <resources> inside of it. And the styles.xml I put the second part of your code but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent.NoActionBar"
```

and

in **styles.xml**

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Transparent.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```